# Overlaying of charts

Tags: overlay, google-visualization

I want to know whether this is possible using Google Charts API: First, create a bar chart with the given input data. And then overlay a line chart (or a line) on top of it.

My use case here, is to show a student's performance in a test when compared to the rest of the crowd which is already available as a bar chart.

**EDIT:** Dug and found out about *markers*. Will explore and may be answer my own question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered pretty explicitly in the current documentation, see [compound charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/compound_charts)

Comment: it seems this answer was ok until 2019 on which it seems the endpoint is deprecated. @rjohnston would you say this is another fair approach to get the same result? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/overlays

Answer (score 1):

Yes, markers are probably what you are looking for. In particular, you may wish to look at a newer feature called "[financial markers](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/styles.html#financial_markers)". This (little advertised) [feature was added recently](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api/browse_thread/thread/73b57d02c28efaf5).